# How to rename sbt dependency file names

Tags: sbt

I have some dependencies from an internal repository. I don't want to include the group and version information in the jar files for these dependencies after packaging.

Dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   ...
   MY_OWN_GROUP % "some_dependency" % MY_OWN_VERSION,
   ...
)
```

When I run `sbt dist` instead of generating a `MY_OWN_GROUP.some_dependency.MY_OWN_VERSION.jar` in the lib folder, I want to generate `some_dependency.jar` without the group and version.

I tried to search documentation of the `sbt`, `Ivy`, sbt source code, but I can't find anything useful.

Your help is very appreciated.

Some related docs for my own reference:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html#Reload+and+create+a+.zip+distribution

---

More thinking:
Seems like there is no easy way to configure it to resolve the issue. Below solutions can be the directions I can explore.

1. Add a customized task in the `sbt dist` to rename the files in the zip file
2. In CI pipeline, after the build, run an extra procedure in the CI pipeline to rename the files
3. Mark the files as provided. In CI pipeline, add jar files into the lib

Comment: May I ask why? If your purpose is to "hide" things, the JAR will still contain classes with their original names likely including "my_own_group".

Comment: Also, in terms of troubleshooting, it's often useful to know the origin of a JAR.

Comment: You can look at shading techniques, not recommended but might be an answer to your question.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thank you for your suggestions. There is a third-party procedure that requires there is no group and version information. And the procedure is out of my control. So I'm thinking change the file name on my side. I will take a look at the shading techs.

Comment: @GaëlJ The shading tech seems not fixing my issue. It's renaming the namespaces. But I want to rename the file names. But thank you for your information still!